# SSIS 2008 Error sending dynamic files as attachment on email task

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, email-attachments

I have a SSIS package where I am exprting data and creating four TXT files with the exported data. The filenames are dynamically generated to include the current date and time so it will look like 'Export1_140723_**1230**.txt" were we have the name with the file number and the timestamp **HHmm**.

Then I am emailling the file using a email task. The package takes some time to export data and there lies the problem. When it tries to include the created files into the attachments the error appears:

> [Send Mail Task] Error: Either the file "Export1_140723_**1230**.txt"
>   does not exist or you do not have permissions to access the file.

The file is created but has the name "Export1_140723_**1231**.txt" since the process took some time and the minute passed.

- The file names are variables that concatenate the "Export" with the
  current date using an expression. I have set the EvaluateAsExpression = TRUE. Then passed the filename to the Flat File Connection also using expressions and with DelayValidation = TRUE

> "Export1_" + SUBSTRING( (DT_WSTR, 30) @[User::Date], 9, 2)
>                   + SUBSTRING( (DT_WSTR, 30) @[User::Date], 4, 2)
>                   + SUBSTRING( (DT_WSTR, 30) @[User::Date], 1, 2)
>                   + "_" + SUBSTRING( (DT_WSTR, 30) @[User::Date], 12, 2)
>                   + SUBSTRING( (DT_WSTR, 30) @[User::Date], 15, 2)            +".txt"

- @[User::Date] is just the GETDATE() expression that I also use in another part of the package.
- Finally the email task has another expression for FileAttachments with DelayValidation = TRUE to fill the filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible way to deal with this issue:

1. Create a new variable that does not evaluate as an expression. This will be used to take a 'snapshot' of your expression variable's original value.
2. Add a script task -before- the email task
3. Add your original expr variable to 'ReadOnlyVariables' in the script task config
4. Add your new non-expr variable to 'ReadWriteVariables' in the script task config
5. In the main method of the script, assign the value of the original expr variable to the new variable like so:

   Dts.Variables["User::NewVar"].Value = Dts.Variables["User::OrigVar"].Value.ToString();
6. Lastly, in the email step, call your new variable (NewVar) for the filename which should contain the value of the original expression.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and althoug it is not the complete solution made me solve the problem. I managed to make it work with a script task. Since my issue had more than one file and they are Date dependent I had to get the date inside the script task and use that date to build the filename, flat file connection and mail attachments.

Comment: Glad you got it working! I probably should have elaborated more on my answer to include multiple files and some other details. I had the same issue a while back and this worked for me. Like you, I've also used the script task to get the date in the past but had forgotten. That's a good solution.  Cheers.